# JavaFX TableView Ignore empty cells when sorting

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have problems when sorting columns when there are empty cells.

I created a new `Comparator` for my `codeMed` column:

```
codeMed.setComparator(new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {

            if (o1 == null)return -1;
            if (o2 == null) return -1;
            return o1 < o2 ? -1 : o1 == o2 ? 0 :1;
        }
    });
```

At first, it seems to work fine:

[image: It works !]

But if I decide to sort a different column then sort the codeMed column this happens:

[image: It doesn't work :(]

I imagine the error is in the Comparator but I don't know what is the problem.

**EDIT**: I want that the null values will always be at the bottom of the column. I tried something like that:

```
if (codeMed.getSortType() == TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING) {
    return (o1 != null ? o1 : Integer.MAX_VALUE) - (o2 != null ? o2 : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
} else if (codeMed.getSortType()==TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING){
    return (o1 != null ? o1 : Integer.MIN_VALUE) - (o2 != null ? o2 : Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}
return 0;
```

But it doesn't work :/ (Maybe because of the problem that Slaw suggests)

My solution:

Thank you very much Jai, I adapt your code just because I want to use it for 2 different columns:

```
Comparator<Integer> integerComparator = new Comparator<>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            final boolean isDesc = tabInfosPatient.getSortOrder().get(0).getSortType() == TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING;
            if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return 0;
            else if (o1 == null) return isDesc ? -1 : 1;
            else if (o2 == null) return isDesc ? 1 : -1;
            else return Integer.compare(o1, o2);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised it even worked once. This is what I think would work well:

```
codeMed.setComparator(new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return (o1 != null ? o1 : Integer.MAX_VALUE) - (o2 != null ? o2 : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    });
```

This would assume any `null` value is treated as if it represents the largest possible `int` value. This would force it to move to the bottom of the list in an ascending sorted column, or at the top if it is in a descending sorted column. If the reverse is desired, switch `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

What you did doesn't work because you have violated this:

> **The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y,
>   x)) for all x and y.** (This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an
>   exception if and only if compare(y, x) throws an exception.)

An example of this violation is when `o1` is `5` and `o2` is `null`. In this case, `compare(o1, o2)` returns `-1` and `compare(o2, o1)` returns `-1` as well. One of them should return positive value while the other negative value, or both must return `0`.

#### Update

This is what you need.

```
public class Model {
    private final ObjectProperty<Integer> v = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public Model(Integer v) {
        this.v.setValue(v);
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<Integer> vProperty() {
        return this.v;
    }

    public final Integer getV() {
        return this.vProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setV(final Integer v) {
        this.vProperty().set(v);
    }
}

ObservableList<Model> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
list.addAll(new Model(20), new Model(-30), new Model(null), new Model(10));

TableView<Model> tv = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<Model, Integer> tc = new TableColumn<>();
tc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("v"));
tv.getColumns().add(tc);
tv.setItems(list);

Comparator<Integer> ascComparator = (o1, o2) ->
                                (o1 != null ? o1 : Integer.MAX_VALUE) - 
                                (o2 != null ? o2 : Integer.MAX_VALUE);

Comparator<Integer> descComparator = (o1, o2) ->
                                (o1 != null ? o1 : Integer.MIN_VALUE) - 
                                (o2 != null ? o2 : Integer.MIN_VALUE);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Comparator<Integer> defaultComparator = TableColumn.DEFAULT_COMPARATOR;

tc.comparatorProperty().bind(
        Bindings.when(tc.sortTypeProperty().isEqualTo(SortType.ASCENDING))
                .then(ascComparator)
                .otherwise(
                        Bindings.when(tc.sortTypeProperty().isEqualTo(SortType.DESCENDING))
                                .then(descComparator)
                                .otherwise(defaultComparator)));
```

Also, I would want to point out that while using `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` should work most of the time, there is a much higher risk of integer underflow and overflow problem, which I'm not sure if it's a problem for using comparators and comparables.

If you want to be more safe, then do a bunch of if-else:

```
Comparator<Integer> ascComparator = (o1, o2) -> {
    if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return 0;
    else if (o1 == null && o2 != null) return -1;
    else if (o1 != null && o2 == null) return 1;
    else return Integer.compare(o1, o2);
};
```

#### Update again

After looking at what you attempted, I realized that this works:

```
Comparator<Integer> comparator = (o1, o2) -> {
    final boolean isDesc = tc.getSortType() == SortType.DESCENDING;
    if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return 0;
    else if (o1 == null && o2 != null) return isDesc ? -1 : 1;
    else if (o1 != null && o2 == null) return isDesc ? 1 : -1;
    else return Integer.compare(o1, o2);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for you response.
Is there a way to always have the null values at the bottom?

Comment: I'm not sure the magnitude of the return value matters, only if it's negative, zero, or positive. @Couldosh Return results that say nulls are greater than non-nulls and the nulls will go towards the bottom when sorted.

Comment: I edited my question with a try to always have te null values at the bottom

Comment: @Couldosh Updated answer.